# MS Access 2010: Dynamically select distinct values from table 1 using field data from table 2

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have the following two tables in MS Access 2010

Table 1

```
ID | Field_Name_1 | Field_Name_2 | Field_Name_3 | ... | Field_Name_Z
1  |    Value_1   |              |    Value_4   | ... | 
2  |              |    Value_2   |              | ... | 
3  |              |              |              | ... |    Value_Z
4  |              |    Value_3   |              | ... | 
5  |              |              |              | ... | 
6  |    Value_1   |              |              | ... | 
7  |              |              |     Value_4  | ... |
```

Table 2

```
ID_2 | Trivial_Name | dB_Field_Name |
1    | Name_1       | Field_Name_1  |
2    | Name_2       | Field_Name_2  |
3    | Name_3       | Field_Name_3  |
:    | :            | :             |
Z    | Name_Z       | Field_Name_Z  |
```

Is it possible to write a query that yields the following results?

```
ID_2 | Trivial_Name | Value    |
1    | Name_1       | Value_1  |
2    | Name_2       | Value_2  |
2    | Name_2       | Value_3  |
3    | Name_3       | Value_4  |
:    | :            | :        |
Z    | Name_Z       | Value_Z  |
```

So, for the Trivial_Name in table 2 retrieve the distinct non-null values for the column in table 1 corresponding to the dB_Field_Name beloning to the Trivail_Name in table 2.
Is should a 'dynamic' query, e.g. if I add a row into table 2 and a column in table 1, the query represents the changes.

Comment: I think the unpivot is not possible

Comment: Use a UNION query to flatten table1, then join it to table2